# Dynamically link an element in Wordpress site (via jquery)

Tags: jquery, wordpress, dynamic-content

I'm trying to dynamically convert a whole `<div>` into a linked surface in WordPress front page. Ideally it'll be a `<div>` with a background image but it could also be a child `<div>` with text in it.

I've already tried different solutions placing the script at the bottom of the HTML file right before the `</body>` tag, being all similar to this:

```
$(document.body).on('click', '#text-2601-0-0-0' , function() {alert("hi") });
```

I've replaced the link code

```
window.open(URL)
```

with the `alert` in order to minimize errors but still it doesn't trigger NO EVENT when clicking over the `#text-2601-0-0-0 DIV`.

I suspect the problem is because of dynamically generated code. I'm making use of an advanced WP theme (by Themify.me) that could be causing problems too.

Do you any have a clue?
Thanx in advance,
hip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In wordpress you need to use jQuery instead of $ so your code should be

```
jQuery(document).on('click', '#text-2601-0-0-0' , function() {alert("hi") });
```

You need to include the above line in your footer (or at least after the div #text-2601-0-0-0 is created in your html file)

Comment: Here you have provided an example of event delgation. So `You need to include the above line in your footer` is not required